# Issue with FilePond when adding files using jQuery Question

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, filepond

Don't use JQ and file pind upload file

I'm facing an issue with FilePond while attempting to add files to the input field using jQuery. Here is my code:

`var inputDesc = document.getElementById("inpImgDesc"); FilePond.create(inputDesc, {     allowMultiple: true,     labelIdle: 'Kéo & Thả hoặc Click để chọn tệp',     labelFileProcessing: 'Đang xử lý tệp...',     labelFileProcessingComplete: 'Xử lý hoàn tất',     acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],     imagePreviewMaxHeight: 300,     imagePreviewMaxWidth: 300, });`
And I've tried a few methods to add files to FilePond:

`Method 1: var pond = FilePond.find(document.getElementById('inpImgDesc')); $.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){     photos.forEach(photo => {         var parts = photo.path.split('/');         var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1]         $.get("http://localhost:8080" + photo.path).then(function(response) {             var file = new File([response], fileName);             pond.addFile(file);         });     }); });`
Method 2:
var pond = FilePond.find(document.getElementById('inpImgDesc')); $.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){     photos.forEach(photo => {         const file = {             source: "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/realestate/src/main/resources/static" + photo.path,             options: {                 type: 'local', // This is a local path             },         };         pond.addFile(file);     }); }); `Method 3: $.get("http://localhost:8080/photo?realEstateId=" + paramProject).then(function(photos){     photos.forEach(photo => {         const file = {             source: photo.path,             options: {                 type: 'local', // This is a local path             },         };         pond.addFile(file);     }); });`